# Eclipse CDT C/C++ Build Command error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

(sorry for my bad english...)

I'm trying to build my .so library in Eclipse, with the CDT plugin. (It's an android project, with native code...)

I changed the build command [Project->Properties->C/C++ build] to suit my needs:

```
C:\SDK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd
```

But I got this message in the console:

```
C:\SDK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd 
Cannot run program "C:\SDK\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd": Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
Error: Program "C:/SDK/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build.cmd" is not found in PATH
```

I tried with only "ndk-build.cmd" in the eclipse's build command, and the path to this command in my PATH environment variable, but I still have the same error. In fact, I can't execute any program from the eclipse's build command.

I have no problem to build the library when I call ndk-build.cmd in cmd.exe, but when I try to automate the library's build in Eclipse, it doesn't work...

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment. Click Add... and set name as PATH, value as your NDK_ROOT, I met the same problem and slove with it